# Reading a widowed pipe hangs

Tags: c, pipe

According to `pipe (2)`,

> A pipe whose read or write end has been closed is considered widowed.
> Writing on such a pipe causes the writing process to receive a SIGPIPE
> signal.  Widowing a pipe is the only way to deliver end-of-file to a
> reader: after the reader consumes any buffered data, reading a widowed
> pipe returns a zero count.

It was my understanding that reading from a pipe that is closed should cause the reader to return with 0 bytes read. However, in the test program below, the `read` call blocks, and the program hangs. I feel as if I must be missing something on the `man` page; why does this program block?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void child(int pipe) {
        close(pipe);
}

void parent(int pipe) {
        char b;
        ssize_t nread;

        printf("about to read\n");

        nread = read(pipe, &b, 1);

        printf("nread = %zd\n", nread);
}

int main(void) {
        pid_t pid;
        int pipes[2];

        pipe(pipes);

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
                child(pipes[1]);
        else
                parent(pipes[0]);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always count fds.  After `pipe`, you have 2.  After fork, you have 4.  After the close, you have 3.  Two for reading, one for writing.  You need to close the other write side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to close the write end of the pipe in the parent process before the pipe is *truly* closed.

Comment: After the `fork` you should close the unused ends of the pipe in both processes immediately (or after `dup`ing if that's the use-case)